# PHP Function and encoding result into JSON

Tags: php, android, json, parsing

I'm trying to call a function and pass the result in a json object in PHP. Everything is working fine except the function part. I keep getting an error of End of Input at Character 1 of.

Here's the line that's causing me trouble

```
$ImageCount =  getCount($fullName);
$response["count"] = $ImageCount;
```

Here's the full file:

```
<?php
$response = array();

include 'db/db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';

$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');

//Get the input request parameters
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); //convert JSON into array

//Check for Mandatory parameters
if(isset($input['username']) && isset($input['password'])){
    $username = $input['username'];
    $password = $input['password'];
    $query    = "SELECT full_name,password_hash, salt FROM member WHERE username = ?";

    if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($fullName,$passwordHashDB,$salt);
        if($stmt->fetch()){

            //Validate the password
            if(password_verify(concatPasswordWithSalt($password,$salt),$passwordHashDB)){
            $ImageCount =  getCount($fullName);
            $response["status"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Login successful";
            $response["full_name"] = $fullName;
            $response["count"] = $ImageCount;
        }else{
            $response["status"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Invalid username and password combination";
        }
    }else{
        $response["status"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Invalid username and password combination";
    }

    $stmt->close();
    }
}else{
    $response["status"] = 2;
    $response["message"] = "Missing mandatory parameters";
}
//Display the JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

My getCount() function code:

```
function getCount($fname){
    global $count;
    $path = 'MobileApp/Images/'; 
    $slash = '/';
    $fullpath = $path.$fname.$slash;
    //echo $fullpath;
    $fi = new FilesystemIterator($fullpath, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $count = (iterator_count($fi));
    return $count;
}
```

Comment: are you getting an error at php side or android side?

Comment: @Exception PHP side. If i remove the troublesome line of code everything works perfect. but once I add it. I get the error (the error is passed to android as "result" which i display on logcat).

Comment: What troublesome line you are talking about?

Comment: @B001ᛦ I don't see it. I have no issue working on wifi or Mobile data. Also my issue is with using the function to get value and pass it in JSON. my JSON is working fine. As i could pass whatever value I want in $count. however when I call the function getCount() I get the error. Also I have tested the function separately and it works fine.

Comment: @Exception $ImageCount =  getCount($fullName);

Comment: Please check my answer below

Comment: **Warning** [Check the `password_hash()` manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). It specifically says DONT generate your own SALT as it is done (and probably more reliably) by the `password_hash()` function. In fact doing your own salt is deprecated in PHP7 so will soon be removed as a possibility. If this is new code, I suggest you dont create your own salt

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks. I will fix it out. However, I'm facing more immediate error atm with my getCount(). when I add it to the code my json doesn't work for some reason. any input ?

Comment: Do you know what is being returned by `getCount()`

Comment: What is in the table column `full_name`

Comment: Yes. When I call the function from another php file (my testing file) it works fine. It returns the number of files in a specific destination. i.e 6

Comment: full_name is a column in my member table.. it has a string. for instance "saeed-1" or "1".

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem lies in the  getCount()  function.

PHP supports count() to get number of elements in the array.

```
count

(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)

count — Count all elements in an array, or something in an object
Description
count ( mixed $array_or_countable [, int $mode = COUNT_NORMAL ] ) : int
```

Please check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: I have updated my question to include getCount() function

Comment: you have defined function as `getImagesCount()` but you have written `getCount()`... change it and retest

Comment: That's my mistake. I copied the old name by mistake. be sure I'm calling the function with the right name.

Comment: I think that is only issue you are calling function which is no not exists

Comment: Im calling getCount(). and my functions is named getCount(). Could you elaborate please?

Comment: `$ImageCount = isset($fullName) ? getCount($fullName):0;`    I hope getCount() works fine..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197822/discussion-between-exception-and-saeed-joul).